# Is there a light web template system that compiles before deployment to static HTML?

Tags: html, templates

I'm currently building a website using static HTML/CSS. I can put in a PHP backend if necessary, but I'd like to avoid this additional complexity if possible.

The site has about 10 different HTML pages, and any change to the navigation bar or other layout elements requires manually implementing the change on all the separate HTML documents.

Is there any simple solution where I can implement a layout template in HTML containing header and footer, and then have separate content files for each page, and compile this all to static HTML before deploying? I suppose I could roll my own in Python but it would be nice if there was a pre-existing solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Template-Toolkit](http://template-toolkit.org/) includes the [ttree utility](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/tools/ttree.html) which does that.

Answer (score 0):

I also subsequently came across [nanoc](http://nanoc.stoneship.org/) which is in Ruby, and seems like perhaps a more modern option.